# Error installing pydev

Tags: java, python, eclipse, pydev

I have eclipse 3.7 installed and I'd like to install pydev from pydev.org/updates from help>install new software but I keep getting errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6253600369144568995.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6253600369144568995.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile571100381995937794.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile571100381995937794.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7939549393376543178.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7939549393376543178.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7919082619115038876.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7919082619115038876.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5333565376705188952.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5333565376705188952.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5676238210588307882.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5676238210588307882.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4716582641827617890.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile4716582641827617890.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile853205344535319189.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile853205344535319189.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6242038948772764722.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6242038948772764722.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6200571740568092132.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6200571740568092132.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7348469738343374780.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7348469738343374780.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3577420456810055714.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3577420456810055714.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3341085924253320715.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3341085924253320715.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3845056374345623111.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3845056374345623111.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6508149376440133601.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile6508149376440133601.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2272439666869250515.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile2272439666869250515.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile3096660355605659228.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile3096660355605659228.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5752308523522565836.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile5752308523522565836.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7961459825015698127.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile7961459825015698127.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.0.0.201311051910.
Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile448758150516384194.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /tmp/signatureFile448758150516384194.jar
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this will fix the problem, but one workaround solution may be to uncheck "Show only the latest versions of available software" on the install dialog box where you choose the version of PyDev to install.

Alternatively, you could manually install PyDev by downloading the zip file and extracting it to the eclipse/dropins folder.

You can find the latest version of PyDev here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/

The second solution is as noted in the PyDev manual:
http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

Hopefully one of these approaches fixes the issue. :)

Comment: Worked for me when I choose the previous version instead of the latest (3.0)

Comment: The manual method worked for me - after installing the key (not sure if required), I simply unzipped the file downloaded from SourceForge into the eclipse/dropins folder and re-started eclipse.

Comment: I tried all of these on Mars.1 with CDT and pyDev many times with little success. Issue may have initially been due to changing python versions/folders and/or latest version of pyDev. Doing -clean and removing \workspace\.metadata\.plugins\py* and uninstalling pyDev plug-ins fixed it. Re-installing pyDev plug-in from repo broke it again. Uninstall and install via first link here worked! Dunno what is different between repo and link/dropin method, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I was having problems with installing all versions of PyDev from 3.0 onwards while using Ubuntu, even when using the zip file supplied on the PyDev website for a while, but here is the solution to get it working.

Up to date versions of Eclipse may complete the PyDev installation using Eclipse's install feature with "http://pydev.org/updates", but even though installed PyDev will do nothing. (You can skip to **step 2** if you are in this situation) Older versions of Eclipse will show the above error. However, both old (at least going as far back as the version on the Ubuntu Software Center, 3.7.2) and new versions can use PyDev 3.0+ perfectly if you follow these instructions.

**Step 1:**

Go to the ([PyDev website](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html)) and download the zip file for Pydev 3.0 or higher.

Navigate to ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_*VERSION*/ (in Ubuntu, not sure where the Eclipse folder would be in Windows) and create a folder called "dropins". Copy the contents of the downloaded zip file to this new folder.

**Step 2:**

PyDev will now be installed, but wont do anything until you download Java 7, so you need to type the following commands into a terminal:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer

sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-set-default

***If you are using Windows** you should probably be able to just download and install Java 7 from the Oracle website and stop here.*

**Step 3:**

Java 7 will now be installed, but it is possible that Eclipse will no longer start. If this is the case you need to type the following into the terminal on **32-bit** systems:

ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86/

Or the following on **64-bit** systems:

ln -s /usr/lib/jni/libswt-* ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/

PyDev 3.0+ should now be working fully in Eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

The [pydev](http://pydev.org/download.html) site states as requirement that the version of eclipse should be 3.8/4.2 (JUNO) and upwards.

I ran into the same problem, updated eclipse and the problem vanished.

A more descriptive report from the installer would have been nicer.