# Installing PyDev in eclipse is failed

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

```
Unable to read repository at http://pydev.sf.net/updates/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:  
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find  
valid certification path to requested target
```

I am installing pydev in Eclipse for using python, but it doesn't install successfully. It gives the above error. What happened? How to solve this error?

Comment: I used these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20207341/error-installing-pydev

Comment: What way you followed to install PyDev? You can follow Market place

Answer (score 2):

I also had this error when trying to install it on a laptop behind a corporate firewall. I couldn't tell you the setup of the firewall, so not sure of the root cause.

I got passed the error by installing PyDev into Eclipse when out from the behind the firewall.

Another way I got around it was to have Eclipse on a non-firewalled machine, install PyDev into Eclipse, and then copy the whole Eclipse directory from the non-firewalled machine to the firewalled machine.

There is probably a better way, and a way to fix it properly, but I didn't have the time to work out what the firewall was doing.

This was on a windows 7 machine (yeah I know) so it probably will not work for *nix versions installed through a package manager like yum or apt.

Answer (score 1):

Install PyDev from Eclipse Marketplace:

1. Open eclipse -> Click Help | Eclipse Marketplace...
2. Search "PyDev" from Eclipse Marketplace pop up window
3. Click Install
4. Eclipse will guide you the next steps
5. After successful installation: Go to Window | Preferences -- PyDev is enlisted at the left side